# Cypress.io cannot find any element, body or class

Tags: iframe, cypress, embedded-documents

I've started testing a .jsp page which includes iframes.

After visiting the page it cannot find a single element, img, class etc etc.
Even using the playground selector it doesn't seem to recognize any link or elements.
I'm unsure if I need to target the iframe first or not.

Below is a recording of the playground selector not finding anything.
https://recordit.co/aQC6Awpxwy

I've added a screenshot of some source code below to help if anyone has any suggestions I can try.
Looks to be #Documents embedded inside of iframes, I have no idea where to start.

[image: html_code]

Comment: I ran into the same issue a while ago and what I did to fix it was load the iframe and then within the iframe i would find the element. `cy.iframe('[id="iframeId"]').find('[id="elementId" ]').click();` see here for more info  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe

Comment: Hi @ItsNotAndy thanks for the reply.
Unfortunately this is still not working for me after installing the npm package and using that function.
It just doesn't seem to find anything! :(